# Как убрать пагинацию для кастомных типов Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Всем доброго времени суток, вопрос заключается в том, что когда в настройках Wordpress на странице *Настройки > Чтение* я указываю количество отображаемых записей (*Например*, `10`), то эти настройки распространяются на все типы записей, даже на те, которые не нужны. Например есть тип `project` (портфолио) и тип `post` (блог), так вот в портфолио пагинация не нужна, а в `post` нужна. Что можно сделать в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алтернативный ответ, потому как *иногда*, если мы находимся на архивной странице мы можем все равно видеть навигацию и `404` в ней. Вставляется в `functions.php`

```
function my_post_count_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    if(is_post_type_archive('your_custom_post_type')){ // поменять на свое
       $query->set('posts_per_page', 100);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_count_queries' );
```

Comment: а как быть, если количество постов может каждый раз увеличиваться? каждый раз править значение? хотелось бы защититься от этого, но -1 здесь не работает и `wp_count_posts` тоже

Comment: что значит каждый раз увеличиваться? "-1" говорит что выводить все посты, и не бить их по страницам. в данной конструкции -1 работает. А вы, просто ради прикола, пробовали наоборот слишком большое значение? 99999

Comment: ради прикола нет, пока поставил 1500. ну вот -1 у меня как раз и не работает.. У меня постов >100 если ставлю 100, то выведет ровно 100, а остальные - нет, значит на число реагирует и считает, но -1 не воспринимает. А у вас работает?

Comment: Вместо posts_per_page=-1 попробуйте numberposts=-1

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо редактировать цикл вывода записей. 
Во всех шаблонах где выводятся необходимые рубрики в цикле WP строку:

```
<? php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Заменить на:

```
<?php 
query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=100');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Вместо 100 указать количество записей на странице для данной рубрики.
Не забудьте закрыть условие if.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы вывести абсолютно все записи в параметре `posts_per_page` нужно указывать -1.